# Error 404 in my api from MAILCHIMP API returns 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

I am making a project on Newsletter of web development by angela Yu and a project of NewsLetter is going on in which I got 404 error which includes API from The MAILCHIMP website and when I put the api inside it and everytime it is howing error 404

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const request = require("request");

const app = express();
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.get("/",function(req,res)
{
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/signup.html");
});
app.post("/",function(req,res)
{
var firstName = req.body.fName;
var lastName = req.body.lName;
var email = req.body.email;

var data = {
    members: [
        {email_address: email,
        status: "subscribed"
        }
    ] 
};

var jsondata = JSON.stringify(data);

var options={
  url: "https://us18.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/3328c667f4",
  method:"POST",
  headers: {
      "Authorization" : "removed"
  },
  body: jsondata
};

// console.log(firstName,lastName,email);
  request(options,function(error,response,body)
  {
    if(error)
    {
        console.log(error);
    }
    else{
        console.log(response.statusCode);
    }
  });
});

app.listen(3000,function()
{
    console.log("Server is listening on port 3000");
})
```

Comment: I removed your credentials, please change them in your mailchimp console

Comment: ty sir checking

Comment: till sir its showing 404

Answer (score 0):

There can be quite a few scenarios where you may face the 404 not found error.

Follow [this](https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/websites/website-creation/what-does-the-404-not-found-error-mean/) blog that describes those scenarios and how to resolve them.

**Your case:**

You are trying to access a list which is might be identified by the ID `3328c667f4`.

This list is a resource. There is a possibility that this resource has been deleted or moved to any other location.

The webserver could not find it on the specified URL and that is why you get 404 not found error.

Comment: ok sir ty for telling me this

Comment: sir till now its showing 404

Comment: Have you changed the URL?

Comment: actually sir mailchimp has a new version so its not showing the place where i have to take that url exactly

Comment: but this which i got is ig is wrong

Comment: if u know mailchimp tell me that

Answer (score 0):

I can relate your problem cuz, at last night I was faced the same problem so... here is your solution

Hopefully its helpful

```
const request = require("request")
const https = require("https")
app.post("/",(req,res)=>{
    FName=req.body.first_nm;
    LName=req.body.last_nm;
    Email=req.body.email;
    console.log(FName,LName,Email);
    // res.send("Detail posted");
    const data = {
        members:[{
            email_address:Email,
            status:"subscribed",
            merge_fields:{
                FNAME:FName,
                LNAME:LName
            }
        }]
    };
    const JSONData = JSON.stringify(data);
    const url="https://usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/listid"
    options={
        method:"POST",
        auth:"apikey:your apikey"
    }
    //jshint:request module is use to make different method(usually post)
    const request = https.request(url,options,(response)=>{
        if (response.statusCode===200){
            res.sendFile(__dirname+"/success.html");
        }else{
            res.sendFile(__dirname+"/failure.html");
        }
        response.on("data",(data)=>{
            console.log(JSON.parse(data));
            
        });
    });
    request.write(JSONData);
    request.end();
});
```